# MySQL Batch Insert

Tags: mysql, batch-file, insert

I'm having the following problem with the Batch Insert of MySQL.

I read a number of records from an MDB file, in order of an ID. I batch-insert them into MySQL, in the same order as read from the MDB-file. 
In the MySQL table the records appear to be in a random order, checkable because the ID from the MDB-file is one of the columns. I expected the order to be the same??

Any ideas what is causing this?

Thanks, 
Steven

Answer (score 1):

The rows in a MySQL table are not guaranteed to be stored "in order", either in the order you insert them or any other order.

The *ONLY* guarantee that you have that rows will be returned by a query in a particular sequence is an `ORDER BY` clause included in your query, e.g.

```
SELECT *
  FROM mytable
 ORDER BY mycol ASC
```